# Why isn't my javascript function working throughout the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to set a section on my site to use toggle buttons that will expand a paragraph. The problem is, the function is working on the first button, but any button after that is not working. Any ideas?

Here is my script

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    var elem = $("#toggle").text();
    if (elem == "Read More") {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read more state
      $("#toggle").text("Read Less");
      $("#text").slideDown();
    } else {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read less state
      $("#toggle").text("Read More");
      $("#text").slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<h2>WEIGHT LOSS</h2>
<span id="text" style="display: none"><p>Regular sauna use can reduce overall body fat. Near infrared light has been shown to  decrease cellulite. NIR heat lamp saunas allow specific problem areas to be targeted as needed. (E.g. cellulite in thigh skin). A study involving a group of women riding stationary bicycles demonstrated a 444% increase in weight loss for the group exposed to near infrared light when compared to the exercise only group.  Infrared light combined with other therapies has been shown to be effective in controlling cellulite.</p>
    
    <p>A two-phase, sauna weight loss study conducted by Binghamton University in New York revealed that an increase in core body temperature resulted in a decrease in body fat. It concluded that people who used an infrared sauna three times a week for 30 minutes per session dropped an average of 4 percent body fat over a four-month period. For a 175-pound man, that represents a weight reduction of seven pounds.</p>
    
    <p>Participants who experienced infrared sauna weight loss did not change their exercise or diet patterns during the study. Control groups in the study who did not use the sauna showed no drop in weight. The study findings illustrate the significant boost that infrared therapy provides for our weight loss goals.</p>
    </span>
<div class="btn-container">
  <button id="toggle">Read More</button>
</div>
```

Comment: put same class for all the buttons and append click event for that class. Id should be uniq for all so use class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have duplicate IDs

Instead use the class and relative addressing

Also use DIVs instead of spans

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-container>button").on("click", function(e) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (text === "Read More") {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read more state
      $(this).text("Read Less");
      $(this).parent().prev(".text").slideDown();
    } else {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read less state
      $(this).text("Read More");
      $(this).parent().prev(".text").slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<h2>WEIGHT LOSS 1</h2>
<div class="text" style="display: none">
  <p>Regular sauna use can reduce overall body fat. Near infrared light has been shown to decrease cellulite. NIR heat lamp saunas allow specific problem areas to be targeted as needed. (E.g. cellulite in thigh skin). A study involving a group of women riding
    stationary bicycles demonstrated a 444% increase in weight loss for the group exposed to near infrared light when compared to the exercise only group. Infrared light combined with other therapies has been shown to be effective in controlling cellulite.</p>

  <p>A two-phase, sauna weight loss study conducted by Binghamton University in New York revealed that an increase in core body temperature resulted in a decrease in body fat. It concluded that people who used an infrared sauna three times a week for 30
    minutes per session dropped an average of 4 percent body fat over a four-month period. For a 175-pound man, that represents a weight reduction of seven pounds.</p>

  <p>Participants who experienced infrared sauna weight loss did not change their exercise or diet patterns during the study. Control groups in the study who did not use the sauna showed no drop in weight. The study findings illustrate the significant boost
    that infrared therapy provides for our weight loss goals.</p>
</div>
<div class="btn-container">
  <button type="button">Read More</button>
</div>

<h2>WEIGHT LOSS 2 </h2>
<div class="text" style="display: none">
  <p>Regular sauna use can reduce overall body fat. Near infrared light has been shown to decrease cellulite. NIR heat lamp saunas allow specific problem areas to be targeted as needed. (E.g. cellulite in thigh skin). A study involving a group of women riding
    stationary bicycles demonstrated a 444% increase in weight loss for the group exposed to near infrared light when compared to the exercise only group. Infrared light combined with other therapies has been shown to be effective in controlling cellulite.</p>

  <p>A two-phase, sauna weight loss study conducted by Binghamton University in New York revealed that an increase in core body temperature resulted in a decrease in body fat. It concluded that people who used an infrared sauna three times a week for 30
    minutes per session dropped an average of 4 percent body fat over a four-month period. For a 175-pound man, that represents a weight reduction of seven pounds.</p>

  <p>Participants who experienced infrared sauna weight loss did not change their exercise or diet patterns during the study. Control groups in the study who did not use the sauna showed no drop in weight. The study findings illustrate the significant boost
    that infrared therapy provides for our weight loss goals.</p>
</div>
<div class="btn-container">
  <button type="button">Read More</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `id="toggle"` to reference the buttons. Id's must be unique. That is why your selector only returns the first value. To fix this, simply change `id` to `class` like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle").click(function() {
    var elem = $(this).text();
    if (elem == "Read More") {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read more state
      elem.text("Read Less");
      $("#text").slideDown();
    } else {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read less state
      elem.text("Read More");
      $("#text").slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<h2>WEIGHT LOSS</h2>
<span id="text" style="display: none"><p>Regular sauna use can reduce overall body fat. Near infrared light has been shown to  decrease cellulite. NIR heat lamp saunas allow specific problem areas to be targeted as needed. (E.g. cellulite in thigh skin). A study involving a group of women riding stationary bicycles demonstrated a 444% increase in weight loss for the group exposed to near infrared light when compared to the exercise only group.  Infrared light combined with other therapies has been shown to be effective in controlling cellulite.</p>
    
    <p>A two-phase, sauna weight loss study conducted by Binghamton University in New York revealed that an increase in core body temperature resulted in a decrease in body fat. It concluded that people who used an infrared sauna three times a week for 30 minutes per session dropped an average of 4 percent body fat over a four-month period. For a 175-pound man, that represents a weight reduction of seven pounds.</p>
    
    <p>Participants who experienced infrared sauna weight loss did not change their exercise or diet patterns during the study. Control groups in the study who did not use the sauna showed no drop in weight. The study findings illustrate the significant boost that infrared therapy provides for our weight loss goals.</p>
    </span>
<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="toggle">Read More</button>
</div>
```

You will need to alter the selector for the text element if you intend to have a button control its own text element.

Comment: This will only slide down one text with ID="text" - more than one "toggle" likely means more than one "text"

Comment: As you're using the class selector within your method, all elements with the matching class will be triggered when a single element is clicked.

Comment: If you run my code you will see that is not the case

Comment: @mplungjan OP has not provided enough information to determine how to do so for more than one element. We don't know the relationship between the button and the text and the OP doesn't actually state there is more than one text element. If that is the case, OP should provide some information about how to get reference to those text elements.

Comment: That's correct for the element with ID of text, but the element with ID toggle is assigned to `this` within the context of the on click method.

Comment: @MattMcDonald Whoops... fixed

Comment: Why would he have more than one button and only one text?

Comment: We haven't been told otherwise so we can't assume that is the case. There are definitely use cases for having multiple buttons and one text.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing an element by ID, but IDs must be unique per DOM element.

When you want to reference multiple elements you should do so via a class.

You also need to change how you reference the element within your on click function. Using `this` ensures you're making the changes to the current element (the one being clicked) and not any element that matches your selection.

To be able to control another element related to the trigger, I'd suggest you wrapped them in a parent element (like a `div`) to let you reliably determine the specific element you want to slide.

```
<div>
    <h2>WEIGHT LOSS</h2>
    <span class="text" style="display: none"><p>Regular sauna use can reduce overall body fat. Near infrared light has been shown to  decrease cellulite. NIR heat lamp saunas allow specific problem areas to be targeted as needed. (E.g. cellulite in thigh skin). A study involving a group of women riding stationary bicycles demonstrated a 444% increase in weight loss for the group exposed to near infrared light when compared to the exercise only group.  Infrared light combined with other therapies has been shown to be effective in controlling cellulite.</p>

        <p>A two-phase, sauna weight loss study conducted by Binghamton University in New York revealed that an increase in core body temperature resulted in a decrease in body fat. It concluded that people who used an infrared sauna three times a week for 30 minutes per session dropped an average of 4 percent body fat over a four-month period. For a 175-pound man, that represents a weight reduction of seven pounds.</p>

        <p>Participants who experienced infrared sauna weight loss did not change their exercise or diet patterns during the study. Control groups in the study who did not use the sauna showed no drop in weight. The study findings illustrate the significant boost that infrared therapy provides for our weight loss goals.</p>
    </span>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button class="toggle">Read More</button>
    </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle").click(function() {
    var elem = $(this).text();
    if (elem == "Read More") {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read more state
      $(this).text("Read Less");
      $(this).parent().parent().children('.text').slideDown();
    } else {
      //Stuff to do when btn is in the read less state
      $(this).text("Read More");
      $(this).parent().parent().children('.text')..slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have got the idea right, but while implementing it has gone little wrong. using class is right -> $(".toggle").click(function() { }); but inside you are using class like id here -> $("#toggle").text(); and $(".toggle").text("Read Less");$("#text").slideDown(); etc, instead try using $(this) and $(this).find('#text') instead.